# trigger update another table's counter

Tags: mysql

Can't seem to get this trigger to work... Some help would be appreciated.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_votes;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_votes AFTER INSERT ON votes
UPDATE collections
SET IF(vote = 1, loves, hates) = IF(vote = 1, loves, hates) + 1
WHERE collections.id = NEW.collection_id;
```

When a new 'vote' is recorded in table votes, I want to increment the column 'loves' OR 'hates' in the table collections which holds a count. The votes table has a column called collection_id which corresponds to a record in the collections table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_votes AFTER INSERT ON votes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE collections
    SET loves = CASE NEW.vote WHEN 1 THEN loves + 1 ELSE loves END
        ,hates = CASE NEW.vote WHEN 1 THEN hates ELSE hates + 1 END 
    WHERE collections.id = NEW.collection_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE collections SET loves = CASE NEW.vote WHEN 1 THEN loves + 1 ELSE loves EN' at line 2.

Comment: I can't even get the basic trigger of 
CREATE TRIGGER triggervotes AFTER INSERT ON votes
UPDATE collections
SET loves = loves + 1
WHERE id = NEW.collection_id;
To work

Comment: OK all I did was add delimiter $$ to the start and wrapped the UPDATE statement in FOR EACH ROW BEGIN and END; and it worked.